# Scala parser combinator all but last

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

What is the correct way to parse a list consuming all but the last element using scala parser-combinators?  For example, if I want to parse "spam spam spam spam spam and eggs" into List("spam", "spam", "spam", "spam") ~ "spam and eggs".

If I just use "spam".+, then all the spam is consumed before I get to match "spam and eggs".  Naturally, I could match on "and eggs" but in practice I might already have a complicated "spam and eggs" parser that I'd rather not alter.

Comment: It isn't a complete answer but `("spam and eggs" | "spam").+` would work for this case, if accepting "spam and eggs spam" etc. is acceptable. If not and nobody does earlier, I'll try to answer tomorrow.

Comment: The best I came up with was `def allButOne[T](p:Parser[T]):Parser[List[T]] = ((p ~ guard(p) ~ allButOne(p)) ^^ { case a ~ b ~ c => List(a) ++ c })|(p <~ guard(p) ^^ { a => List(a) })` but wondered if there was a more natural pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple but inefficient version:

```
def allButOne[T](p: Parser[T]): Parser[List[T]] = (p <~ guard(p)).+
```

Comment: That's far more elegant.  Thanks.